# Is it possible that multiple consumers of a Rabbitmq queue get the same message?

Tags: go, concurrency, rabbitmq

I am in charge maintaining a production software written in Golang which uses RabbitMq as its message queue.
Consider the following situation:

1. A number of goroutines are publishing to a queue name *logs*.
2. Another set goroutines read from the queue and write the messages to a MongoDB collection.
3. Each publisher or consumer has its *Own* connection, and its own channel respectively, they are working in an infinite loop and never die. (The connections and channels are established when the program starts.)
4. `autoAck`, `exclusive` and `noWait` are all set to false and `prefetch` is set to 20 with `global` set to false for all
   channels.    All queues are durable with `autoDelete`, `exclusive`
   and `noWait` all set to false.

The basic assumption was that each message in the queue will be delivered to *one and only one* consumer, so each message would be inserted in the database exactly once.
The problem is that there are duplicate messages in the MongoDB collection.
I would like to know if it is possible that more than one consumer gets the same message causing them to insert duplicates?

Comment: I’m not sure what the rabbitmq settings correlate to, but fundamentally you can’t have “exactly once” delivery in a distributed system.

Answer (score 2):

The one case I could see with your setup where a message would be processed more than once is if one of the consumers has an issue at some point.
The situation would follow such a scenario:

1. Consumer gets a bunch of messages from the queue
2. Consumer starts processing a message
3. Consumer commits the message to mongodb
4. either due to rabbitmq channel/connection issue, or other type of issue consumer side, the consumer never acknowledges the message
5. the message as it hasn't been acknowledged is requeued at the top of the queue
6. same message is processed again, causing the duplication

Such cases should show some errors in your consumers logs.

Comment: So the point here is that RabbitMQ don't sent the same message twice  unless your consumer has notified RabbitMQ that failed then RabbitMQ will sent it again depending your configurations. Anyway using message brokers every consumer must be prepared to receive the same message twice  by definition

Comment: Well, taking an extract of [rabbitmq reliability documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html), `Use of acknowledgements guarantees at-least-once delivery. Without acknowledgements, message loss is possible during publish and consume operations and only at-most-once delivery is guaranteed.` I don't agree with @deFreitas statement. The way you set things up combined with what you're trying to achieve and what you can live with will determine whether you'll have at-least-once, at-most-once or neither. Now what I'll agree with is that indeed most setups will target at-least once. :)